# Дефекты с тенями по краям на объектах

Tags: unity3d

Имею проблему с тенями, которую не могу решить. Проблема появилась, когда я перешёл на `Universal Render Pipeline`. Дело в том, что по краям появляются дефекты и их можно убрать либо отключив тени, либо увеличив `Depth Bias` хотя бы до 3.
По поводу второго (т.к. отключить тени - не выход)

[image]

Когда `Depth Bies` равен одному (т.е. до исправлений):

[image]

Когда `Depth Bies` равен трём, то тень немного смещается, что тоже не приятно:

[image]

---

Что мне нужно сделать, посоветуйте пожалуйста? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Картинку прямо в вопрос, а не по ссылке

Comment: Первая картинка вставляется, а следующие две картинки просто как остаётся [Описание] и не сменяется на картинку

Comment: Сейчас в вопросе ни одной картинки не отображается. В редакторе есть кнопка специальная для вставки картинки. Если всё нормально вставилось, то эта картинка будет видна на превью и не будет ссылок никаких в вопросе

Comment: Всё, картинки есть. Будешь ли ты отвечать?

Comment: Не буду отвечать